# audio recording in background on iOS

Tags: iphone, audio, background, location, recording

I have an application that uses location services in the background. Works fine.
But what I want to do, at a certain point, is to check some audio levels while the application is in the background. For some reason it doesn't seem to work. When running in foreground, the function works fine, but when in the back ground, the audio recorder average and peak input is always -120..

This is what I use to do the trick (that doesn't seem to work apparently..)

```
            ....
            [recorder record];
            if (levelTimer == nil) {
                    bgTask = 0;
                    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                    }];
                levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.02 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
            }
            ...
```

And yes, the `levelTimerCallback` is called every 0.02 seconds, even when in the background, so I assume that the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` works fine.

Any thoughts or some hints?

Comment: Have you got it done? I met the same issue, could you please help share some thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the only supported way to record in the background on an iOS device is to include audio for the UIBackgroundModes key in the app's plist, enable an appropriate Audio Session for recording, and start recording (or playing) audio before the app goes into the background.

If the app uses the Audio Queues or the RemoteIO Audio Unit API for recording, the buffer callbacks can just throw away all the audio buffers until the time of interest, and then compute the energy represented by the PCM samples for the amount of time required when needed.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think iPhone will allow recording in the background. Only few services are allowed when the app goes into background. Logically if your app stays into background for a long time it would then consume a lot of battery as well as buffer to store audio, unless you have time and memory managed these resources. This would also pose issues for your app when you submit it to the App Store.

Although you can refer to this link for knowing what can be run in the background.
I hope this might help u clear things in a way.

[iPhone : Running services in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252575/iphone-running-services-in-the-background)

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, kind of figured it would go this way. I only thought that when you specifically tell the app to keep running in the background, all services would work. And as for memory management  etc, I only need to record for a few seconds, and that's it.

Comment: Actually your decision is to record it for few seconds.. But not all developers would want that. perhaps someone in future would want it for a greater period. that ways it will be impossible for apple to allow such things in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

There is an app I know of that has background recording. Beatmaker 2. You need to turn run in the background on in the settings of device under beatmaker 2.  In beatmaker create an audio track and start recording. Them use the home button on device to exit app but its still recording. You can get creative with different interfaces as well. I do this to feed the iPhone 4 line out into an audio track in beatmaker 2. You can record the audio of anything playing in the foreground. (YouTube videos apps music from your iTunes library. You can edit the waves also after recorded.