# Prevent Daemon pausing when iPhone locks

Tags: ios, iphone, daemon, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

Developing a daemon for jailbroken iDevices.
It's supposed to run when the iPhone is locked. However, the process seems to be put on hold after a little under a minute when the iPhone is locked (as seen by considering the "Total Process Running Time" given by CocoaTop). How can I prevent this, and make the daemon run all the time?
I'm sure this is possible, since when the phone is charging (plugged in) the daemon is not paused, and I see it working.

Comment: I'm not sure about jailbroken devices, but I know iOS operating system only gives a small amount of time to your application when it is backgrounded to clean up / pause current tasks. I don't think that you can continue to record in the background when the device is locked. you can only try to prevent it becoming locked. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534095/audio-recording-in-background-on-ios

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to use [a daemon](http://bbs.iosre.com/t/run-a-daemon-as-root-on-ios/212) to schedule code. And it's supposed to run in the background, too, when locked.

Comment: The reason is that iOS goes to sleep and pauses all the processes. Try searching about preventing iOS from sleeping. There're solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapped the main method of the daemon in what's described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1340/_index.html) under Listing 2